# Strings from strings.xml into fields to use in various methods of the Class or get them with getString whenever needed?

Tags: android, optimization

For example, if I need to use a string of strings.xml "getString(R.string...)" in various methods of the Class I'd better get the string whenever I need to call the getString method or I should put in a variable field? In my project I currently place this in field variables, but the code is getting large and disorganized. And at this link https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html says to avoid to use unnecessary variables. What is the best practice?